# Print a 256-color test pattern in the terminal

Tags: terminal, tmux, colors, xterm

How do I print a 256-colour test pattern in my terminal?

I want to check that my terminal correctly supports 256 colours.

Comment: Please do not crosspost (http://askubuntu.com/questions/821157/print-a-256-color-test-pattern-in-the-terminal).

Comment: My understanding is that that is to prevent time being wasted answering a question already answered. It's entirely relevant to both sites... How to say which is more relevant?

Comment: non Ubuntu related question should redirected here

Comment: Yes - this is not limited to Ubuntu

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**256-colour test pattern**

[image: 256-colour test pattern]

For the above, you can use [my bash code](https://gist.github.com/HaleTom/89ffe32783f89f403bba96bd7bcd1263). ("Look Ma, no subprocesses!")

Or for a bash quicky:

```
for i in {0..255} ; do
    printf "\x1b[38;5;${i}m%3d " "${i}"
    if (( $i == 15 )) || (( $i > 15 )) && (( ($i-15) % 12 == 0 )); then
        echo;
    fi
done
```

---

**24-bit / truecolour test pattern**

See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/404414/143394) for the full spectrum :)

Comment: Not sure why you formatted it this way but at least it works and looks good.

Comment: Suggestions for improvement?

Comment: Works also on zsh

Comment: can try that one `printf "%03d\e[48;5;${i}m   \e[0m " $i;`

Comment: On bash, `printf` is not a builtin -- so this does indeed use subprocesses

Comment: @Zach R I just did a quick google... What evidence do you have for you assertion it's not a built-in?

Comment: ```
$ bash -c 'which printf'
/usr/bin/printf
$ zsh -c 'which printf'
printf: shell built-in command
```

Comment: Apparently it is a builtin, per the Bash documentation.  Bash just doesn't show builtins with "which". https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man7/bash-builtins.7.html

Comment: @Zach R `type printf`

Answer (score 8):

Install an application named `colortest`

and use the following commands to test the ASCII color graph

```
colortest-8   => Display color palette using 8 colors.
colortest-16  => Display color palette using 16 colors.
colortest-256 => Display color palette using 256 colors.
```

Comment: “Install an application named colortest”—this kind of begs the question. Where does that ``colortest`` package originate? It doesn’t appear to be in the Fedora or Arch repos.

Comment: Said application is available for `ubuntu`.  For more info, refer this link http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1349