# Check if terminal supports 24-bit / true color

Tags: linux, terminal, colors, color-management

In a shell script, how can I test programmatically whether or not the terminal supports 24-bit or true color?

---

Related: [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404414/print-truecolor-24-bit-test-pattern) is about printing a 24-bit / truecolor test pattern for eyeball verification

Comment: Not a direct answer, but if you're OK with falling back to less granular colour, you can just print the 256-color escape code immediately before the 24-bit code (e.g. `\e[48;5;124m\e[48;2;65;0;0m` for a red background). Terminals that don't support 24-bit colour will ignore the second escape code and use the less-precise colour from the palette, while those that do will read it and immediately override the 256-color code.

Comment: @HarryCutts Nice one. Is there a way to map a 24-bit colour to it's closest 8-bit neighbour?

Comment: I couldn't find one after a cursory search, so you might have to write your own. Also, I only tried it with shades of gray before, and now that I'm trying it with colours it seems that the 24-bit code is resetting the background to black, so it might be a bit of a niche solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This source](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728#detection) says to check if `$COLORTERM` contains `24bit` or `truecolor`.

#### `sh`

```
[ "$COLORTERM" = truecolor ] || [ "$COLORTERM" = 24bit ]
```

#### `bash` / `zsh`:

```
[[ $COLORTERM =~ ^(truecolor|24bit)$ ]]
```

Comment: This is not a reliable solution. What if the env variable is not set?

Comment: @jdhao Some variables like `$TERM` are just assumed to be set correctly. If not set, then I'd fallback to checking for 256 colour support myself.

Comment: One thing to note: This works well with local terminals, but when you get into a remote machine (e.g., `ssh`) or a tmux session, the `COLORTERM` variable would not propagate.

Comment: @JongwookChoi `ssh -o SendEnv=MYVAR`

Answer (score 3):

Just use `tput colors`. I believe testing for *terminal capabilities* is a much safer test than parsing `$TERM` or `$COLORTERM` yourself.

```bash
if (( $(tput colors 2>/dev/null) > 256 )); then
    echo "What a beautiful rainbow!!!"
else
    echo "Back to the 80's VGA era anyone?"
fi
```

Of course, `tput` only outputs the *advertised* capabilities as registered in the [Terminfo database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo), so it might not accurately reflect your *actual* terminal capabilities.

Unfortunately, as per comments, many terminals still have wrong or outdated info, specially in platforms such as Windows and MacOS. Hopefully, given enough time (and bug reports!), such terminals will eventually set their `$TERM` appropriately. After all, it's been 4 years since the Terminfo database supports 24-bit colors.

Comment: The problem for a long while was that [until 2018](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#index-t20180121) terminfo _did not_ reflect the number of colours available, which was in turn because the compiled binary format of the terminfo database only permitted 16-bit integers.  It has had to adopt a new binary format.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36163656/340790

Comment: `tput colors` just reports 256 colors unless I set `TERM=xterm-direct tput colors`. Not reliable.

Comment: @tastytea: if your terminal actually supports more than 256 colors with its default `TERM`, then its terminfo database is inaccurate, and that's a bug in your terminal. `tput` is the most consistent method to detect terminal capabilities in a portable way.

Comment: @MestreLion unfortunately it seems like many terminals are buggy in that regard. iTerm2 and Apple Terminal both set `TERM=xterm-256color` by default and don't appear to have a better option, even though iTerm2 definitely does support 24-bit color.

Comment: This fails on Windows Terminal. I got the second response while it appears to be displaying 24-bit colour when using this script: https://gist.github.com/weimeng23/60b51b30eb758bd7a2a648436da1e562

Comment: @paradroid: added a note about Windows and MacOS terminals, and `tput`'s dependency on a properly updated Terminfo and accurate `$TERM`

Answer (score 1):

I have cut this C++ solution from a program of mine.

First, set up termios so you can read one character at a time...

```
#include <termios.h>

  struct termios tio, tio_init;
  tcgetattr(0, &tio_init);         // Keep a copy so you can reset later
  tcgetattr(0, &tio);    
  tio.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF);  // Pass Ctrl-S and Ctrl-Q
  tio.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON); 
  tio.c_cc[VSUSP] = 0;             // Pass Ctrl-Z (confuses terminal)
  tio.c_cc[VMIN] = 0; 
  tio.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &tio);
```

Here's a simple routine that submits an ANSI query, and pulls characters off the reply. We assume the terminal program is fast, and the 1-tick (0.1 sec) term character timeout will tell us when the reply characters stop coming. The terminating '\n' is sometimes needed to get the terminal program to execute the command. It may hang around until it decides a redraw us necessary.

```
void AnsiViewQuery(char *reply, const char *query, int size) {
  printf("%s\n", query);
  int len = 0;
  while (len < size-1) {
    if (read(0, reply+len, 1) == 1) ++len;
    else break;
  }
  reply[len] = '\0';
}
```

We set the foreground colour to 1;2;3, and then see if we can read it back again...

```
  char reply[32];
  printf("\e[38;2;1;2;3m");
  AnsiViewQuery(reply, "\eP$qm\e\\", 32);
  int truecolor = strncmp("\eP1$r0;38:2::1:2:3m", reply, 19) ? 0 : 1;
```

This is not foolproof. I want to set 24-bit colours but I do not need to read them back. This test passes if both writing and reading work. Some terminals such as the Gnome terminal support one but not the other. If it thinks truecolor is supported, it should be right. Maybe you can improve this.

The same program outputs a unicode character and checks the cursor has moved by one character, to check the particular unicode set is supported.